# Control animation on the a-frame-alongpath-component

Tags: animation, aframe

The problem is autoplay-animation that I want to disable at the start.

I thought why not to start this sentence

> AFRAME.registerComponent('track1', { <

The code is getting messy and Im trying to figure out both functions 'remove' and ´play' on the  #track1.

Clicking on the "animate button" sets function 'play' on the #track1.

The code 'triggers:a-curve-point' inside the aframe-along-component.js always trigger the animation so soon a curve is established like #track1.

> AFRAME.registerComponent('alongpath', {

```
//dependencies: ['curve'],

schema: {
    curve: {default: ''},
    triggers: {default: 'a-curve-point'},
    triggerRadius: {type: 'number', default: 0.01},
    dur: {default: 1000},
    delay: {default: 0},
    loop: {default: false},
    rotate: {default: false},
    resetonplay: {default:true}
},

init: function () { <
```

[The link to Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/saber-harsh-meteor)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Help us help you: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example on how to create a minimal reproducible example and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks. I think I did everything. It looks like that along-path-component is not really suitable for controlling an animation. I even removed the animation code though it triggers anything automatically (the code is "triggers: a-point-curve;" once two points are created). Otherwise one has to modify build.js from scratch. I'm not capable of that. 

I could modify the SVG animation from AnimeJS by adding "autoplay:false" and voila!

I will close the question in a few days.

Comment: One idea I have is https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/core/component.html#aframe-registercomponent-name-definition. Disable or pause the component "track1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although it would be best to extend the `alongpath` component with some flow control, you can achieve a `play` / `stop` / `reset` functionality without it.

- add the component dynamically to simulate `play()`
- call  its `.reset()` method to reset the animation:

  ```
  AFRAME.registerComponent("track1", {
    init: function() {
      var box = document.querySelector("a-box");
      document.querySelector(".enter").addEventListener("click", e => {

        if (box.components.alongpath) {
          // if the component is attached - reset
          box.components.alongpath.reset();
        } else {
          // otherwise attach it
          box.setAttribute("alongpath", "curve", "#track1");
        }
      });
    }
  });
  ```

Check it out [here](https://stack-65530960.glitch.me/) (click the fish to see the source).

Comment: I tested to change the script to accomodate "a-entity" and "a-camera" instead of "a-box". I just replaced the word "box" with "entity" or "camera". It seems not working. 'code'AFRAME.registerComponent("track1", {
      init: function() {
        var camera = document.querySelector("a-camera");
        document.querySelector(".enter").addEventListener("click", e => {
          if (camera.components.alongpath) {
            camera.components.alongpath.reset();
          } else {
            camera.setAttribute("alongpath", "curve", "#track1");
          }
        });
      }
    });

Comment: Would be easier within a fiddle, here you have with [a-entity](https://jsfiddle.net/L712cusf/1/), and [a-camera](https://jsfiddle.net/L712cusf/2/), let me know if it helps

Comment: if you want to grab by the `camera` component, then you need to use a selector `[camera]`

Comment: I put together two answers I got from you. I guess some way of ".emit" has to be embedded and allow the use of track1,2 and 3 by clicking on box, sphere and cylinder. I'm still scratching my head how  tying "click each object" to every track. https://jsfiddle.net/tomasis/a5rwfs2g/36/